# Azure QnA Maker matches with questions only or answers also?

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

We are working on QnA maker to get user queries. We suspect that the keywords from the user entered queries not only match the questions but also match with answers.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

User queries will match with the answer pair it was trained with and will also match other answers based on confidence scores

For example a QnA Pair of

```
Question: "What is your name?"
Answer:   "My name is Azure"
```

If a user query was "What is your name?" The answer will be "My name is Azure" with a confidence score of 100 as it is an exact match to that Question and Answer Pair.

If a user query was "Tell me your name?" and assuming there is no question pair with that question in the knowledge base, the answer will also be "My name is Azure" but with a lower confidence score of say 50.

See here below of how confidence scores between queries and the knowledgebase pairs are calculated. Hope this helps!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/confidence-score